# sforce.one not available in VF page used as CTI adapter

Tags: visualforce, cti, lightning-message-service

We are using a VF page as a CTI adapter. It does not seem to include `sforce.one`. I notice on other VF pages this is brought in as part of `api.js`, but I cannot put my finger on what it is about that VF page which brings in api.js  when the CTI adapter page does not bring it in.

How do I access sforce.one from my VF page acting as a CTI adapter? Would it be a horrible idea to bring it in explicitly myself, as in

```
<apex:includeScript value="/sforce/one/50.0/api.js"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The recommended approach is documented in the Open CTI developer guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_connecting.htm)

Using the below imports in Lightning Experience brings in the required `sforce` dependency

```
<apex:page>
      <script src="/support/api/50.0/lightning/opencti_min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 ...
 </apex:page>
```

I tested by creating a simple vf page as shown below with the call center config as [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_call_def_file_sample.htm)

```
    <apex:page >
  <!-- Begin Default Content -->
    <h1>Sample Page in CTI!</h1>
    <!-- End Default Content -->
     <HTML>
      <head>
       <!-- Imports Open CTI JavaScript library. Point to a valid Salesforce 
  domain.
  -->
    <script src="https://domain:port/support/api/50.0/lightning/opencti_min.js">.    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   // Callback of API method: setSoftphonePanelHeight
    var setSoftphonePanelHeightCallback = function(response) {
        // Returns true if setSoftphonePanelHeight method is executed successfully, false otherwise
        if (response.result) {
           alert('setSoftphonePanelHeight is successfully executed.');
        } 
  };
   // Invokes API method: setSoftphonePanelHeight
   function setSoftphonePanelHeight() {
     sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelHeight({
        heightPX: 500,
        callback: setSoftphonePanelHeightCallback
     });
  }
   // Callback of API method: setSoftphonePanelWidth
       var setSoftphonePanelWidthCallback = function(response) {
        // Returns true if setSoftphonePanelWidth method is executed successfully, false otherwise
        if (response.result) {
           alert('setSoftphonePanelWidth is successfully executed.');
        } 
        else {
           alert('setSoftphonePanelWidth failed.');
        }
  };
   // Invokes API method: setSoftphonePanelWidth
   function setSoftphonePanelWidth() {
     sforce.opencti.setSoftphonePanelWidth({
        widthPX: 500,
        callback: setSoftphonePanelHeightCallback
       });
    }
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
  <button onclick="setSoftphonePanelHeight();">setSoftphonePanelHeight({heightPX:500}). 
 </button><br/>
   <button onclick="setSoftphonePanelWidth();">setSoftphonePanelWidth({widthPX:500})</button><br/>
   </body>
  </html>
</apex:page>
```

You can use the `sforce.opencti.publish` method to publish an LMS event directly to an LWC component that can be on the app page!

LWC component can help with you all the functions like navigation, refreshing or any other thing you need sforce.one for.

sforce.one is only available on top frame in lightning experience or in the Salesforce mobile app container

You can bring in sforce lib as you have mentioned in query but it is not documented method

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you kindly confirm that you also have access to `sforce.one`, since we need that to use LMS (`sforce.one.publish`)? We were actually already bringing in `opencti.js`, and we see `sforce`, but not `sforce.one`.

Comment: I found out I can use `sforce.opencti.publish`. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_sample_lex_message_service.htm.

Comment: Exactly I was about to update this! You can use LMS there and use publish and then once in LWC you don't need sforce.one for anything!